# Чем можно заменить запись

Tags: c

Чему будет равно выражение `arr[i] % 2 && arr[i] % 6`, если использовать в if и чтобы выполнилось?
 `arr[i] % 2 == 0 && arr[i] % 6 == 0` или  `arr[i] % 2 == 1 && arr[i] % 6 == 1`
Не до конца понимаю

Answer (score 1):

В C нет настоящего булевого типа. Роль булевых значений играют целые ноль и единица. Оператор `&&` возвращает единицу если оба его аргумента не равны нулю, иначе - ноль.

Выражения `A && B` и `A != 0 && B != 0` вычисляют одно и то же значение (иногда нужно добавить скобки).

В нашем случае `arr[i] % 2 && arr[i] % 6` равносильно `(arr[i] % 2 != 0) && (arr[i] % 6 != 0)`. Скобки надеты для ясности, обычно их не пишут. Языку не важно как вы записали выражение, легче читать вариант с `!= 0` - целые значения явно преобразуются в булевы.

Выражение `arr[i] % 2` для положительных `arr[i]` может быть нулём или единицей. Можно написать `(arr[i] % 2 == 1) && (arr[i] % 6 != 0)`. Ещё раз оговорюсь, эта замена верна только если вы уверены что `arr[i] >= 0`.

Вторую скобку, с шестёркой, никак не переделать, если записывать компактно.

Я бы писал так: `arr[i] % 2 != 0 && arr[i] % 6 != 0`. Читается как "`arr[i]` не делится на два и не делится на шесть".

Comment: `Аргументы оператора && приводятся к булевому типу.` На самом деле нет. В C операнды оператора `&&` просто сравниваются на неравенство `0`. Если оба не равны нулю, то результатом оператора `&&` будет значение `1` типа `int`.

Comment: @wololo, ваш комментарий довольно точно повторяет первый абзац. :)

Comment: Я имел в виду, что в C++ операнды оператора `&&` приводятся к типу `bool` — это часть алгоритма вычисления выражения. В C такого шага — приведение к булевому типу — просто нет. Ну и ладно.

Comment: @wololo, исправил. Спасибо! Не знаю, хорош ли ответ. Какие-то лоскутки и повторения.